# How can I generate child model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to model the following.

I have a `parent model` that is called `Brick` that has some attributes.
There will be 5+ type of bricks that will all have their own specific attributes which are needed also.

I want to be able to select all Bricks of a certain customer id later, whatever the type (TwitterBrick, facebookBrick et cetera)  is.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// set up a mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Brick', new Schema({ 
    type: String, 
    userid: { type: String, required: true},
    animationspeed: { type: Number, min: 1, max: 100 }, 
    socialsite: String,     // none, twitter, instagram
    socialsearchtags: String,
    tagline: { type: String, minlength:3,maxlength: 25 },

}));
```

An example for a child is `TwitterBrick`.
for now it is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
module.exports = mongoose.model('TwitterBrick', new Schema({ 
    bgColor1: String, 
    bgColor2: String,
    bannerBgColor1: String,
    bannerBgColor2: String,
}));
```

TwitterBrick should inherit the attributes of Brick, but I don't know how.
Can you help me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to set a new "content" field in brickSchema, and split in different files:

**brick.schema.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = { 
          type: String, 
          userid: { type: String, required: true},
          animationspeed: { type: Number, min: 1, max: 100 }, 
          socialsite: String,     // none, twitter, instagram
          socialsearchtags: String,
          tagline: { type: String, minlength:3,maxlength: 25 },
          content: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: false, default: null}
    }
```

**brick.model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BrickSchema = new Schema(require('brick.schema.js'));
module.exports = mongoose.model('defaultBrick', BrickSchema, 'Bricks');
```

**twitterBrick.model.js**

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
  var brickSchema = require('brick.schema.js');

  brickSchema.content = new Schema({
  bgColor1: String, 
  bgColor2: String,
  bannerBgColor1: String,
  bannerBgColor2: String,
});

var BrickSchema = new Schema(require('brick.schema.js'));
module.exports = mongoose.model('twitterBrick', BrickSchema, 'Bricks');
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: thanks for your help! I'm trying it out now. Is it possible to get the different kind of brick models into 1 collection with this approach?

Comment: Of course You can have multiple schemas on one single collection ! Check my edit for declaration :)

Comment: oh i'm really a noob :).... i get "path must be a string" error at "brickSchema.content = require({....". Do you know what went wrong?

Comment: Don't know if it is the right way but i got it working by changing the "required" into "schema".... "brickSchema.content = new Schema({
  bgColor1: String, 
  bgColor2: String,"

Answer (score 1):

Just add the Brick model as an attribute (composition).
It will compensate for that.
Or just rely on exisiting mongoose plugins for that https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend
check this one out.

Comment: hi, I'm trying the schema-extend solution right now but run into an error, (i added it as an answer). Do you know how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't **"require" the previous file**, so technically it's out of scope and the TwitterWallBrickSchema doesn't have a clue what's a "BrickSchema".
***Either you put the two models in the same file , or require the first file in the second file***.